# Sub menu not showing in joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have problem in joomla to show sub menu.I have create multi language site and i have near 500 menus. Now some of the old submenu i deleted and add new sub menu under parent menu. but those sub menu is not showing on my live server but it is showing on my local machine.

For eg. I have parent menu Product and its menu id is 112 and i have another main menu(parent) called about us and its id is 120. now if i create submenu under the product it is id is auto incremented like (620). it new sub menu showing on my local machine but on live server it is not showing. so suppose if i change that submenu id to 119 then it will display on the product menu. but the submenu id is grater than 120 then is is now showing.

Please help me.

Comment: I found it kinda confusing to follow the whole story with the menus/submenus and their ids. Someone should have to put his hands on, to figure out what's going on there.

Answer (score 2):

Your question does not provide much information, but as a guess only:

1. Ensure that `Show Sub-menu Items` is turned 'On' for every menu module in your site. This is [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621073/joomla-sub-menus-not-appearing) already.
2. How do you sync local machine and live server?
3. How do you intend to change ID of a menu item? Bear in mind that direct modification in Joomla database could make your site total loss.
4. This could be template issue - please provide live demo.
5. Last but not least - [clean](https://docs.joomla.org/Help34:Site_Maintenance_Clear_Cache) Joomla cache after modifications.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have check show Sub-menu Items and it`s turn on. And I am not sync to live and local server. I have copy of same code which i run on my local server. when i add sub menus in local environment it`s work fine. but if i do same process to add menus from admin in live server it`s not display those menu.

Comment: OK. In that case it is possible to be connected with your template and with some js scripts, which do not run on your server, but executed in localhost. Do you have any errors in browser console? Without link to your site it would be difficult to guess.

Comment: No there is no error related with the jquery. I had debug script  i used mod_menu module for menu and in **helper.php** this function is used **getList** and in get list `$app = JFactory::getApplication(); 
  $menu = $app->getMenu(); $items   = $menu->getItems('menutype', $params->get('menutype')); ` when i debug $items on both local and live server. In local server it is showing newly added menus in to the object but on live server it is not. I am not understand it is realted with PHP setting or something else.

Comment: Yes, it would be usefull to check PHP version. Try to add parent menu (not sub menu items) and make it vissible to super user (you) only. Can you see it?

Comment: No it is not show me as well. I have also added one parent menu.I have check php version on live server it`s 5.3.29 and in local it`s 5.4.x .

Comment: PHP version should be OK. Did you make any direct modifications in the database? Can you compare both tables `_menus`? I suppose you get no error when creating sub-menus, but do you see them in the backend after that?

Comment: Yes, I have check that as well. and setup same code on another server again. it`s working on that server as well. I think it is related with server setting or php setting which is different on server.

Answer (score 0):

login to control panel back-end.go to Extensions->module->main-menu-> Show Sub-menu Items. by default its off you just on and save